# How to get multiple parameters from API call in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

Need some help here as I am very lost in something that should be very simple. Either that or I am losing my mind.

Ok so I am routing my routes using the express.Router()

I will jump right to the problem:

This works:

```
apiRouter.get('/api/user/:id', secureAPIPages, function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
        if(user){
            res.json({
                fullname:   user.fullname,
                about:      user.about,
                birthday:   user.birthday,
                email:      user.email,
                location:   user.location
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Result does not exist');
       }
    });
})
```

So when I make a call on a browser like:
http://localhost:3000/api/user/123456

It picks up the "id" variable and puts it in the req.params so all good there.

Now, the problem (this is what I want to make work, the above one is just to test out if my API routing worked):

```
apiRouter.get('/api/user', secureAPIPages, function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
        if(user){
            res.json({
                fullname:   user.fullname,
                about:      user.about,
                birthday:   user.birthday,
                email:      user.email,
                location:   user.location
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Result does not exist');
       }
    });
})
```

Why is it not picking up my "id" and "name" variables when I run this URL on a browser:
http://localhost:3000/api/user?id=123456789&name=Shayan

As always, thanks for the help in advance.

Shayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use query object as follows:

If this is the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/user?id=123456789&name=Shayan
```

use

`req.query.id, req.query.name`